# draw arc between 2 lines & draw a curve 2 points

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Framework: fabricjs

My first problem is to draw a angle betweens 2 Lines. My code is working but i'm not happy with the result.

My second problem is to draw a curve between 2 Points.

My Code for the first problem.
I have 3 Points: 
A , B , C

2 Lines:
AB , BC

With this information i calculate distance points with distance 10.

```
let angle = this.calcAngle(A,B,C);
let distanceAB  = this.calcCornerPoint(A, B, 10);
let distanceBC = this.calcCornerPoint(C, B, 10);
```

Calc Angle:

```
  calcAngle(A, B, C, final, finalAddon = "°") {

    var nx1 = A.x - B.x;
    var ny1 = A.y - B.y;
    var nx2 = C.x - B.x;
    var ny2 = C.y - B.y;

    this.lineAngle1 = Math.atan2(ny1, nx1);
    this.lineAngle2 = Math.atan2(ny2, nx2);

    if (nx1 * ny2 - ny1 * nx2 < 0) { 
      const t = lineAngle2;
      this.lineAngle2 = this.lineAngle1;
      this.lineAngle1 = t;
    }

    // if angle 1 is behind then move ahead
    if (lineAngle1 < lineAngle2) {
      this.lineAngle1 += Math.PI * 2;
    }

  }
```

Than draw a Path with:

```
this.drawAngleTrapez(distanceAB, distanceBC, B);

drawAngleTrapez(AB, BC, B) {
    let points = [AB, BC, B];
    let path = "";
    if (this.trapezObjs[this.iterator]) {
      this.canvas.remove(this.trapezObjs[this.iterator]);
    }
    path += "M " + Math.round(points[0].x) + " " + Math.round(points[0].y) + "";
    for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      path += " L " + Math.round(points[i].x) + " " + Math.round(points[i].y) + "";
    }

    this.currentTrapez = this.trapezObjs[this.iterator] = new fabric.Path(path, {
      selectable: false,
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      hoverCursor: 'default',
      fill: '#ccc',
      strokeWidth: this.strokeWidth,
    });
    this.canvas.add(this.trapezObjs[this.iterator]);
  }
```

And than i draw a Circle:

```
drawAnglePoint(B,d = 10) {
    this.currentCorner = new fabric.Circle({
      left: B.x,
      top: B.y,
      startAngle: this.lineAngle1,
      endAngle: this.lineAngle2,
      radius: 10,
      fill: '#ccc',
      selectable: false,
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: false,
      hoverCursor: 'default',
    });
    this.canvas.add(this.currentCorner);
  }
```

But the result ist not beautiful:

[image]

And the blue point is not on the end of the line, mabye here also a little fix.

```
this.startPoint.set({ left: C.x, top: C.y });
```

Second Problem solved: was an error in my calculation.

The problem is , its not a beautiful curve:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the result is not beautiful" on the first issue? Can you please better describe your expectations in that case?

Comment: white space between the 2 obj

Answer (score 0):

Rather than draw the central 'wedge' as 2 shapes - a triangle and a portion of a circle, you should instead draw it as the 2-sided figure that it is.

Circles are drawn by supplying the origin. Therefore, to draw the blue point on the end of the line, you should specify the same coordinates for the end-point as you do for the circle-centre.

The below code will re-create your first image with the exception of the text.
While I've drawn the swept-angle indicator transparently, ontop of the lines, you'd probably want to change the draw order, colour and opacity.

(I used 0x88/0xFF = 136/255 = 53.3%),

```js
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

class vec2
{
 constructor(x,y){this.x = x;this.y = y;}
 get x(){ return this._x; }
 set x(newVal){ this._x = newVal; }
 get y(){ return this._y; }
 set y(newVal){ this._y = newVal; }
 get length(){return Math.hypot(this.x,this.y);}
 set length(len){var invLen = len/this.length; this.timesEquals(invLen);}
 add(other){return new vec2(this.x+other.x, this.y+other.y);}
 sub(other){return new vec2(this.x-other.x, this.y-other.y);}
 plusEquals(other){this.x+=other.x;this.y+=other.y;return this;}
 minusEquals(other){this.x-=other.x;this.y-=other.y;return this;}
 timesEquals(scalar){this.x*=scalar;this.y*=scalar;return this;}
 divByEquals(scalar){this.x/=scalar;this.y/=scalar;return this;}
 setTo(other){this.x=other.x;this.y=other.y;}
 toString(){return `vec2 {x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}}` }
 toStringN(n){ return `vec2 {x: ${this.x.toFixed(n)}, y: ${this.y.toFixed(n)}}` }
 dotProd(other){return this.x*other.x + this.y*other.y;}
 timesEquals(scalar){this.x *= scalar;this.y *= scalar;return this;}
 normalize(){let len = this.length;this.x /= len;this.y /= len;return this;}
 static clone(other){let result = new vec2(other.x, other.y);return result;}
 clone(){return vec2.clone(this);}
};

window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoaded, false);

function onWindowLoaded(evt)
{
 var can = byId('output');
 let A = new vec2(172,602), B = new vec2(734,602), C = new vec2(847,194);
 myTest(can, [A,B,C]);
}

function circle(canvas, x, y, radius)
{
 let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.moveTo(x,y);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.ellipse(x,y, radius,radius, 0, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fill();
}

function getAngle(origin, pt)
{
 let delta = pt.sub(origin);
 let angle = Math.atan2( delta.y, delta.x );
 return angle;
}

function myTest(canvas, points)
{
 let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
 // background colour
 //
 ctx.fillStyle = '#ebedf0';
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

 
 // white square grid
 //
 //60,33 = intersection of first
 //115 = square-size
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
 ctx.lineWidth = 12;
 for (let x=60; x<canvas.width; x+=112)
 {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 for (let y=33; y<canvas.height; y+=112)
 {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 
 
 // wedge indicating swept angle
 let angle1 = getAngle(points[1], points[2]);
 let angle2 = getAngle(points[1], points[0]);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(points[1].x,points[1].y);
 ctx.arc(points[1].x,points[1].y, 70, angle1,angle2, true);
 ctx.fillStyle = '#cccccc88';
 ctx.fill();
 console.log(angle1, angle2);

 // lines
 //
 ctx.lineWidth = 9;
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#c3874c';
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
 ctx.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
 ctx.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

 // points
 //
 ctx.fillStyle = '#3b89c9';
 ctx.beginPath();
 points.forEach( function(pt){circle(canvas, pt.x,pt.y, 10);} );
 ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
 zoom: 67%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='output' width='996' height='730'></canvas>
```